# In VS code snippet how to reuse a transforms like a variable to avoid write the transform again and again?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

For example I want to reuse this transform like a variable in my snippet instead of write the transform again and again

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)$/${1:/pascalcase}/}
```

```
    "example": {
        "prefix": "example",
        "body": [
            "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)$/${1:/pascalcase}/} ${1:name1} = _${1};",
            "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)$/${1:/pascalcase}/} ${2:name2} = _${2};",
            "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)$/${1:/pascalcase}/} ${3:name3} = _${3};",
            //...
        ],
        "description": "example"
    },
```

Comment: :(, thanks can you check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59963489/make-a-vscode-snippet-that-can-use-a-variable-number-of-arguments-and-use-variab

Answer (score 4):

You can repeat the same transform by assigning it to a placeholder and referencing that number, like this:

```
  "example": {
    "prefix": "example",
    "body": [
      "${4:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)$/${1:/pascalcase}/}} ${1:name1} = _${1};",
      "${4} ${2:name2} = _${2};",
      "${4} ${3:name3} = _${3};",
    ]
  }
```

Comment: That is a very nice technique.  I didn't know you could do that.