# use dollar sign in a vscode snippet regex

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to make a vs code php snippet which generate this line from the `$code` placeholder input:

```
Utils::getLogger.debug("code", ["code" => $code])
```

The regex I use for this is `/(\$?)(.*)/` (I am interested in the second capture group to get the variable name).

This is my snippet code :

```
"log debug": {
    "prefix": ["log debug", "debug"],
    "body": ["Utils::getLogger.debug(\"${1/(^\\$?)(.*)/$2/}\", [\"${1/(^\\$?)(.*)/$2/}\" => ${1:variable}])"],
    "description": "Quick variable debug."
},
```

**The problem is** that it doesn't replace the dollar sign from my input. If I give `$variable` as placeholder, it generates `Utils::getLogger.debug("$variable", ["$variable" => $variable])`.

I got it working for a charater different than the dollar sign, for example a comma or another letter and also I got it working using `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` variable and selecting my variable before.

I suspect that it is a conflict with vs code php variable name autocompletion in vscode as if I copy my variable then call the snippet and paste the variable inside the placeholder (instead of typing it), it also works.

I was tempted to post this as an issue on vscode github but maybe am doing something wrong here.

ps: I know that is can also type in the variable name without the `$` and add it in the replacement regex, but you know how developpers can be...

Comment: I tried your snippet and it works as expected, it removes the `$` if present, the `$` is only removed when you tab out of the `${1}` field, it can be simplified to `${1/^\\$?(.*)/$1/}`

Comment: Why did you change  the second transform to `(^,?)(.*)` from `(^\\$?)(.*)`?  If you make those both `(^\\$?)(.*)` it works as you expected.  And you don't need the `^` regex start indicators - they aren't doing anything here.

Comment: the second capture group `(^,?)` was a test with another character, I was not used in the "final" snippet. i edited

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for the simplification, but the problem is still present, more information on my reply to Mark (TLDR: https://imgur.com/Wa9yaI7)

Comment: I have no PHP extensions installed, you can file an issue with the PHP extension that it should not complete variables inside strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions and further testing, I think there is nothing wrong with the snippet code and it is a "conflict" with php variable autocompletion.

There are some optimisations in the answers that are interesting tho.

For information, I finally took the solution to enter the variable name without the `$` and add it in the transform.

```
"log debug quick": {
    "prefix": ["log debug quick", "debug quick"],
    "body": ["Utils::getLogger.debug(\"${1:variable}\", [\"${1}\" => \\$${1}]);"],
    "description": "Quick variable debug."
},
```

Note that the original method works with the `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` variable (as the autocompletion does not happen), so the folowing is working :

```
"log debug selection": {
    "prefix": ["log debug selection", "debug selection"],
    "body": ["Utils::getLogger.debug(\"${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^\\$?(.*)/$1/}}\", [\"${1}\" => $TM_SELECTED_TEXT]);"],
    "description": "Quick variable debug."
},
```

*Note that I optimized the snippet with both @Mark and @rioV8 suggestions*

Comment: And I guess nobody noticed that i used `.` instead of `->` in php, well, me neither until now that I am actually using my snippet...

Answer (score 1):

This works:

`"body": ["Utils::getLogger.debug(\"${2:${1/\\$?(.*)/$1/}}\", [\"$2\" => ${1:variable}])"],`

Note that since you are reusing the first transform, I set it to a placeholder `${2}` by wrapping it like so:

`${2:${1/\\$?(.*)/$1/}}`

Now you can reuse that `$2` placeholder wherever you want the **result** of the same transform - as in `\"$2\" =>`.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66449064/836330 for that usage.

[image: snippet demo removing $]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, this is a nice feature but it does not solves the issue, but I am now pretty sure that my issue is a conflict with php symbol autocompletion as demonstrate the test I did with your snippet code (same results with mine) :  

https://imgur.com/Wa9yaI7  

The second capture group `(^,?)` was a test with another character, it was not used in the "final" snippet(i edited)